# Why does this capture group capture a single character but not everything that the capture group covers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

#input_example
capture_where_capsule = "((PL_ADVB='la gran biblioteca rápidamente y luego llegamos allí')hacía)"


list_all_adverbs_of_place = ["de allí", "de alli", "allí", "alli", "de allá", "de alla", "allá", "alla", "arriba", "abajo", "a dentro", "adentro", "dentro", "a fuera", "afuera", "fuera", "hacía", "hacia", "encíma de", "encima de", "por sobre", "sobre"]
place_reference = r"((?i:\w\s*)+)"
pattern = re.compile(r"\(\(PL_ADVB='" + place_reference + r"'\)" + rf"{'|'.join(list_all_adverbs_of_place)}" + r"\)", re.IGNORECASE)

m1 = re.search(pattern, capture_where_capsule)
if m1:
    place_reference_string = m1.group()[1]
    print(repr(place_reference_string))
```

Why does this capturing group fail to capture all this substring?

The parentheses of the capturing group enclose the entire pattern that should be responsible for capturing the text that matches.

The substring that should capture would be this substring (and not other):

```
'la gran biblioteca rápidamente y luego llegamos allí'
```

Comment: `m1.group()` is the matching string `alli`. Adding `[1]` selects the 2nd character of the match.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried that too, but the problem is that I can't catch the whole string  `'la gran biblioteca rápidamente y luego llegamos allí'` and not only `"allí"`. Below I have indicated the correct output, but I think the parentheses of the capturing group are well delimited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all the alternatives in a group. Otherwise, only the first alternative is concatenated to the `((PL_ADV...)` part of the regexp.

Then use `m1.group(1)` to get that capture group. `m1.group()[1]` is the 2nd character of the entire match.

```
pattern = re.compile(rf"\(\(PL_ADVB='{place_reference}'\)({'|'.join(list_all_adverbs_of_place)})\)", re.IGNORECASE)
m1 = re.search(pattern, capture_where_capsule)
if m1:
    place_reference_string = m1.group(1)
    print(repr(place_reference_string))
```

Comment: Thank you, I had not taken into account that I should include the alternatives on the list in a group ()